# how to know maximum number of character which can fit for a line in vscode editor

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

how to know maximum number of character which can fit for a line in vscode editor based upon its view port? Basically i need to programmatically  wrap the given text as if user has set Editor.wordWrap setting to ON.